# how to get part of string by regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to get part of string by regular expression I try this but it returns more than I need. This my code :

```
Release_name = 'My Kitchen Rules S10E35 720p HDTV x264-ORENJI'
def get_rls(t):
    w = re.match(".*\d ", t)

    if not w: raise Exception("Error For Regular Expression")
    return w.group(0)


regular_case = [Release_name]
for w in regular_case:
    Regular_part = get_rls(w)
    print(">>>> Regular Part: ", Regular_part)
```

This code for this example " `My Kitchen Rules S10E35 720p HDTV x264-ORENJI` "
return this "`My Kitchen Rules S10E35` " but i do not need the "`S10E35`" just return this `My Kitchen Rules`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
w = re.match(r"(.*?)\s+S\d+E\d+", t)
```

and since the value you need is in Group 1:

```
return w.group(1)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/DDDJnZ), output is `>>>> Regular Part:  My Kitchen Rules`.

**Pattern details**

- `(.*?)` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `S\d+E\d+` - `S` char, 1+ digits, `E` and 1+ digits

The `re.match` will only start matching from the start of the string, `^` at the start of the pattern is not necessary.